# data from tradingview with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to get this code to print the values for Ehlers MAMA by scrapping data from the tradingview website. here is my code. It returns a blank array when I run it.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

# example option: add 'incognito' command line arg to options
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument("--incognito")

# create new instance of chrome in incognito mode
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=option)

# go to website of interest
browser.get("https://www.tradingview.com/chart/vKzVQllW/#")

# wait up to 10 seconds for page to load
timeout = 10
try:
    WebDriverWait(browser, timeout).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]")))
except TimeoutException:
    print("Timed out waiting for page to load")
    browser.quit()

# get all of the titles for the financial values
MAMA_element = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div/div[3]/div[3]/div/span[3]/span")

print(MAMA_element)
```

this is a sample of what i'm trying to print the "7498.984". but like I said I get a blank array returned

```
<span class="pane-legend-item-value pane-legend-line xh-highlight" style="color: rgb(255, 0, 255);">7498.984</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print(MAMA_element.text)
```

You may want to strip it

```
print(MAMA_element.text.strip())
```

Comment: Thank you .text was all i needed